# How to compare generic EF Core entities with composite keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a question regarding how to best compare EF Core entities with a composite key.

So, the reason why I initially came up with this requirement was that I am currently working on a generic repository (Yes, I know people have a very split up opinion of this), and wanted to implement a CreateOrUpdate method for a list of entities. The signature would look like this:

```
public async Task CreateOrUpdate(List<TEntity> entities, Action<TEntity> updateFunc)
```

So, EF Core already offers the `ValueTask<TEntity> FindAsync (params object[] keyValues)` method, which retrieves a single entity based on a set of keys. However, there's nothing built in for a list of methods. Keep in mind, that FindAsync will do a DB query if nothing was found, so this means that e.g. calling this for 500 items might mean 500 DB queries, which is pretty wasteful in my opinion.

What I was thinking instead was that I could instead to it a bit different, by overriding Equals and using a regular .Where statement, so something along those lines:

```
public async Task CreateOrUpdate(List<TEntity> entities, Action<TEntity> updateFunc)
{
    await using var ctx = CreateContext();

    var set = ctx.Set<TEntity>();

    var existingItem = await set.Where(x => entities.Contains(x)).ToListAsync();

    ...

}
```

So, I was now wondering: Is this a proper approach? Can I just make all my TEntity types override Equals and do it like this? Sadly I can't just constrain all my TEntity types to an interface which supplies an "Id" property and compare that, as I also have a few entities providing a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

No, `IEquatable` will not help. You have to create huge predicate to solve this problem.

Basically it should looks like this (sorry writing from memory)

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> FilterByPrimaryKey(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<T> items, Model model)
{
   var pk = model.FindEntityType(typeof(T))
      .FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Select(p => p.PropertyInfo).ToArray();

   var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
   Expression predicate = null;

   foreach (var item in items)
   {
      var obj = Expression.Constant(item, typeof(T));
      var matchPredicate = pk.Select(p => 
        (Expression)Expression.Equal(
           Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, p),
           Expression.MakeMemberAccess(obj, p)
        )).Aggregate((e1, e2) => Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2));

      predicate = predicate == null ? matchPredicate : Expression.OrElse(predicate, matchPredicate);
   }

   predicate ??= Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(2))
 
   var lambda = Expression.Lambda(predicate, param);

   var whereExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", 
      new[] {typeof(T)}, 
      query.Expression,
      lambda
   );
 
   return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereExpr);
}
```

BUT, finally you will find that this solution has high memory usage and CPU consuming and probably will fail on big items list.

On request I can provide fastest solution using [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) and it's `Merge` operator and probably temporary table usage.